# What Project Template do I choose to make a C++ DirectX DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, directx, project-template

I have a C# XAML UWP project, and I need some 3D stuff in it.
So I figured using DirectX (which requires C++) is the way to go.
So I want to make a new C++ project that builds to a DLL, and use that in my C# project.

But I can't figure out what Project type to use for that. There are types for libraries, and their are other types for creating DirectX apps, but I can't find any that combines the 2.

This may be a stupid question, but I'm really not that familiar with Visual studio, project templates and building dlls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the "Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows)" template. 
I don't know if it's the best choice, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need C++ to have 3D in your C# project.
Just google 'directx in c# tutorial'. Also DirectX is not your only option for 3D. You may want to look at OpenGL. Make sure you go through a few tutorials to get some understanding of 3D stuff.

Comment: That's the first I hear someone say you can use directX without C++. It even says you can't on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/game-development-platform-guide ("Because the DirectX APIs are native, C++ is the only language supported for use with DirectX.")

Comment: I think I found the tutorial you meant: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb153264(v=vs.85).aspx
But these are kinda old, and don't use XAML but forms (I use XAML)

Comment: I've been looking for a way to do this for almost 2 days now, and it really seems to me the only way to have 3D in my project is by either creating a C++ dll, or by using a wrapper like sharpDX, but our team has decided not to use sharpDX because it leaks.

Comment: You will end up writing your own sharpDX. I'd suggest looking closer into the 'leak problem'. Maybe it's broken indeed but maybe someone just used it incorrectly. Also how much will it affect your project?

Comment: I don't want to encourage memory leaks in your code - but it's more important to meet the requirements than having perfect code.

Comment: I agree, that's why I said "our team decided", rather than "I decided". I fear making it myself will likely result in more memory leaks.

Comment: Anyway, I ended up using the "Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows)" template. And that works.
But thanks for trying to help, I appreciate it.